# Styled Component- The purpose of transient props?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I know that when we use javascript or pass props into styled component, a dollar sign prefix is mandatory to run the code.

But there are sometimes when I saw something like

```
const Links = styled.a`

  color: ${(props) => (props.$isActive ? "#8b572a" : "#3f3a3a")};
```

where in the dom it's

```
 <Links
            $isActive={category === name}
            key={index}
            );
            }}
          > </Links>
```

Notice there are both dollar signs before isActive.

If I remove both dollar sign, thing happens just fine.

So why does there a dollar sign?

Comment: It's probably a template literal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thanks for answering, but if I'm not wrong, template literal is the dollar sign at the beginning.

Comment: `$isActive` is just an variable name of props. It's not some special keyword or something. And please mention both scenario what happens with `$` and without `$` in `isActive`. But in template literal if you use `${}` then you can insert some code in strings.